# populate array with random numbers

Tags: ruby

I have the following array:

```
nums = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

and another array that must have 3 items:

```
arr = [1]
```

How can I get one or two items from nums array (random) to populate arr that must have 3 elements?

Comment: Shuffle and take first 3 elements

Comment: Are repeats allowed? That affects which answers given below would be valid.

Comment: I took "one or two items from nums array" to mean _distinct_ items as opposed to "a random item one or more times", but it is worth clarifying.

Comment: I assume from the last sentence that the OP wishes to draw a random sample comprised of either three elements that are the same or two elements that are the same and a third element that is different from the first two. jujajjjj, you should clarify that, however.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Array.sample`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Array/sample)

```rb
arr.concat num.sample(2)
```

Comment: You can use `concat` instead of `<<` (which doesn't require flattening)

Answer (score 1):

You can shuffle the array and take the first three elements to ensure you don't have repeats.

```rb
arr = nums.shuffle.take(3)
```

If, for instance, you were dealing with a situation like a card game where you need to draw from a shuffled deck more than once, you might want to store the shuffled array, and then pop from it.

```rb
shuffled = arr.shuffle
arr = shuffled.pop(3)
# shuffled now only has the remaining two elements
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nums = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
arr = [1]
```

```
2.times { arr << nums.sample }
```

Instead of `sample(2)` it's better to use `sample` without argument I think

Because `sample` with argument returns array with not repeated elements (with not repeated indices to be more precise)

That is, it is more random :)

[Read more](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sample)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to obtain a statistically random sample (subject to the impossibility of computing a truly random number).

---

The first is to select three elements at random and accept it if it contains at most two distinct elements. If it contains three distinct elements reject it and try again.

```
def doit(arr)
  loop do
    a = Array.new(3) { arr.sample }
    return a if a.uniq.size <= 2
  end
end
```

```
nums = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

```
doit nums #=> [40, 40, 10]
doit nums #=> [20, 50, 20]
doit nums #=> [50, 50, 20]
```

---

The second way is to make a probability calculation. Firstly, I assume that `nums` contains unique elements. (That assumption is not a deal-breaker but it avoids the messiness of dealing with the more complex case.)

```
n = nums.size
  = 5
```

First compute the probability of drawing one distinct element (e.g., `[30, 30, 30]`).

```
P[N1] = (1/n)(1/n)
      = (1/5)(1/5)
      = 1/25
      = 0.04
```

Note the first element drawn can be anything, then the second and third draws must match the first draw, the probability of each being `1/5`.

Next compute the probability of drawing three distinct elements:

```
P[N3] = ((n-1)/n)*((n-2)/n)
      = (n-1)*(n-2)/n**2
      = 4*3/5**2
      = 12/25
      = 0.48
```

Again, the first element can be anything. The probability of the second element drawn being different is `(n-1)/n` and the probability of the third element drawn being different than the first two
is `(n-1)/n`.

Lastly, if N2 is the event in which exactly two of the three elements drawn are unique we have

```
P[N1] + P[N2] + P[N3] = 1
```

so

```
P[N2] = 1 - P[N1] - P[N3]
      = 1 - 0.04 - 0.48
      = 0.48
```

We therefore may compute

```
P[N1|N1 or N2] = P[N1 and (N1 or N2)]/P[N1 or N2]
P[N1|N1 or N2] = P[N1]/P[N1 or N2]
               = 0.04/(0.04 + 0.48)
               = 0.04/0.52
               = 0.0769
```

Therefore,

```
P[N2|N1 or N2] = 1 - P[N1|N1 or N2]
               = 1 - 0.0769
               = 0.9231
```

We therefore may write the following to obtain a statistically random sample.

```
def doit(arr)
  if rand < 0.0769
    n = arr.sample
    [n, n, n]
  else
    n1 = arr.sample
    n2 = (arr - [n1]).sample
    [n1, n2, n2]
  end
end
```

```
doit nums #=> [40, 40, 40]
doit nums #=> [10, 20, 20]
doit nums #=> [10, 20, 20]
```